# If username not exist "INSERT INTO" Else "UPDATE" (display info)

Tags: c#, ms-access, asp-classic

this is my table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><b>Utilizador:</b></td><td><asp:Label ID="username" runat="server"></asp:Label></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><b>Telefone da Empresa:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="empresa" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox> (Exemplo: +351234925xxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>2º Telefone:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="empresa2" runat="server" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox> (Exemplo: xxxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Telemóvel:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="telemovel" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox> (Exemplo: +3519xxxxxxxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Guardar" onclick="cmdSave_Click" /></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

i want verify **IF** username exist in database show me the answers to *update* **ELSE** *insert into*

this is my code behind so far. it's to *insert into*

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        username.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]"; 
    }

    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sFilePath = Server.MapPath("Database3.accdb");
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
        string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO colaborador(Empresa,Empresa2,Telemovel,username) VALUES (@Empresa,@Empresa2,@Telemovel,@username)";
        using (Conn)
        {
            Conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertCmd, Conn);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Empresa", empresa.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Empresa2", empresa2.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telemovel", telemovel.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);            
            Response.Write(" ");
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            lblInfo.Text = "Dados guardados!";
            lblInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

my purpose is **before** answer my table **show** the answered questions [or display an message saying "User already answered"] if not exist in my database then display the table to field. 
It's driving me crazy can't to such thing

Comment: Your question is very confusing... If you want to check for the existence of a record before inserting or update it, this operation is called an "upsert", however MSAccess doesn't have an easy way of doing this, so you need to query your database first for the data, and if you don't get any records back, do the insert. Its not clear though what you are trying to check for...

Comment: @RonBeyer How can I query the database first for the data? 
sorry for my bad english. for now I only can save the text.box to my .accdb file.  but i want open the page and with the ` username.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]"; ` verify if the username exist in database. **If yes** show the database **if not** show the table to field the text.box

Comment: C# and asp-classic are a total contradiction in terms.

Comment: @Martha  like i said this driving me crazy. theoretically it seems pretty easy. but i can't get help from anywhere. I pretend open the page and see if the username already exist in database if yes show the row from that specific username else insert into (using my table above)

Comment: @KikoFHM: you misunderstood me. I'm saying that if you're using C#, then you are NOT using asp-classic. The two are impossible to use together. Therefore, the tags on this question are incorrect. Whether the C# code itself is nonsensical or not, I wouldn't know: I'm allergic to curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like this,

```
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 from Table WHERE Username=@NAME" , objsqlconn);//get rows if username exists
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar,20).Value = Master_product_txt.Text;   
objsqlconn.Open();
readr = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (!readr.HasRows) 
{
`// write Code to insert values
}`
else
{
    //write code to retrieve values and update          
}
```

Edited the code as pointed out by  @ A ツ

Comment: i'm confused, you update if no row exists and insert if there is one?

Comment: @learningNew sorry but I'm really new. i want to learn for future understanding. your sample of code is just copy & past in code behind? or i need add <% or protect void

Comment: @Aツ i pretend read the database and if the username already exist show the row from that username if not insert to database using my table questions

Comment: @KikoFHM This code behind just checks if a record already  exists for the username.
you need to add the code for for insert and update in if else blocks. I have not written code for update as dont know which columns you want to update.

Comment: @learningNew in my code i have the table with text.box to user field & in my code behind the action to insert into database. However i don't have any control if the user already asnwered. for example any user can answered 2+ times. but i want prevent to only answer 1 time only.

Comment: @KikoFHM then instead of writing code to retrieve values and update (in else block) you can provide a message to user that the answer can not be updated.

Comment: @learningNew sorry boring you but how can i do that using my code?

Comment: i have this ` protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        username.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]"; 
    } ` to get the username can i read database looking if username already exist in database? and if yes provide a message

Comment: From what I observe from your code is your database interaction @KikoFHM code and UI code are mixed(Which is not a good thing to do,try separating your UI code from data interaction),  but now you can just put a message box that user already exists.
Add this in else block, *MessageBox.Show("User already exists")*